# regex extract value from the string between delimiters

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a large String and I need to extract String value from it. String value is located between delimiters

```
category = '
```

and

```
';
```

This is my regex, but I need to avoid outputing delimiters.

```
String productCategory = Regex.Match(html, @"category = '(.*?)';").Value;
```

This is the exampe
`category = 'Video Cards';`

and I need to extract 
`Video Cards`

Comment: Can u give one sample input string and expected output for that string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can use is the lookahead and lookbehind operators, so you end up with something like:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=category = ').*(?=';)";
string productCategory = Regex.Match(html, pattern ).Value;
```

It's also worth mentioning that [parsing HTML with regexes is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1159478).  You should use an HTML parser to parse HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the `MatchObj.Groups` property?  If you test your current regex at a testing site like [Derek Slager's](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx), you'll notice exactly what you want is the first Group.  You should simply be able to invoke the first Group and get what you need.

```
productCategory.Groups[0].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to extract the group:

```
String productCategory = Regex.Match(html, @"category = '(.*?)';").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, Groups is initialized from zero and this has only one subgroup.  Using Groups[1] would probably throw an out of bounds exception.

Comment: What he's getting in `.Value` is the 0th-indexed group (i.e., `.Groups[0].Value`).

Comment: Incorrect.  Please check [a regex tester](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) with the value 'Video Cards' and the expression '(.*?)' - there is only one Group available.

Comment: @YYY - Your expression is incorrect.  The OP has this expression:  `@"category = '(.*?)';"`

Comment: It is merely interpreted literally and broke the OP's sample data, so it was an error (at least when I was playing with it, the OP has since been updated).  Still, if you add it on it doesn't change the behavior of Groups at all, since the regular expression engine doesn't have a Group there to include, only a character that it must interpret literally.

Comment: Quite so, it worked in VS2010 in a small console app exactly the same way it worked in Derek Slager's RegEx tester.

Comment: *Did you try the code that I posted?*  Not using your expression, but using the OP's expression.  I pasted the code in the pastebin.  Go ahead and try the code that I used.

Comment: Copy-pasted it into my project, used the immediate window to make my results more terse.  Not sure what to tell you, my friend! `Regex.Match(test, @"category = '(.*?)';").Groups[1]
{}
    base {System.Text.RegularExpressions.Capture}: {}
    Captures: {System.Text.RegularExpressions.CaptureCollection}
    Success: false`

Comment: I get a different result:  `Regex.Match(test, @"category = '(.*?)';").Groups[1]
{test}
    base {System.Text.RegularExpressions.Capture}: {test}
    Captures: {System.Text.RegularExpressions.CaptureCollection}
    Success: true` ....

Comment: Well that's bloody weird!  I certainly don't think I have another place to get it, I haven't done any voodoo with RegExs on this machine.  I'll have to look into this more, though that's way out of the scope of this question, I think.